# Autofac component registration/resolution bug?

Tags: autofac

I seem to have a problem - rather unexpected; so I guess I might be doing something silly/wrong.

I register two container scoped services as such:

```
builder.Register<IServiceInfo>(c => CreateServiceInfo(c)).As<IServiceInfo>();
builder.Register<IServiceInfo>(c => CreateServiceInfoSomeOther(c)).As<IServiceInfo>().Named("someOther");
```

Now when I try to resolve

```
container.Resolve<IServiceInfo>()
and container.Resolve<IServiceInfo>("someOther")
```

I get the same instance. I would expect the first call to return the first instance and the second call to return the second instance. Why is this happening this way?

I am hoping there are some active Autofac experts around here and I'd appreciate any help to quickly fix this.

Thanks, all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When two services are registered, the last one wins (it doesn't matter that the second is named, it's still a registration for that service), unless you ask for an instance by name.

You can use ".DefaultOnly()" to modify your second registration so that the first is the actual default.  See the [wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ComponentCreation) for more info.

Comment: I wanted to comment but I don't have enough reputation to do so. This answer was extremely helpful, especially since I couldn't find any documentation for old Autofac versions anywhere online!

Anyone who utilizes this solution should note that it will stop the named registration from working with the IContainer.ResolveOptional<T>(name) method. You'll instead have to use the .Resolve<T>(name) method and wrap it in a try/catch block.